# Xamarin Forms: eliminate switching to "selfie" camera?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I hired a software developer to work on a mobile app, using Visual Studio and Xamarin Forms. I'm currently testing in my iphone.

A functionality of the app is to take a picture. When I take the picture, the screen looks like below. As you can see, the *rotate camera* button at the bottom right will switch to the "selfie" camera.

I asked the developer if that button can be disabled or eliminated so that only pictures are taken with the rear camera (not the selfie camera), and he told me that it's not possible since it's a system camera.

Is there a way to disable the functionality to switch cameras?

We're using the [Xamarin.Essentials: Media Picker class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=android)

[image]

Comment: More of an iOS question than a Xamarin one.

Comment: What API is being used to take the picture?  There is very little useful information here we could use to help you

Comment: I added the Media Picker class that we're using.

Comment: MediaPicker doesn't have a way to do this.  You can either customize it yourself - Essentials is open source - or otherwise you can write your own per-platform camera UI that presents only the options you want

Comment: @Jason, thanks. Are there any other plugins that do this?

Comment: You could refer to [Xam.Plugin.Media](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) which is a free Plugin by James Montemagno, that allows us to easily interact with Capturing Photos with some customization on the UI.

Comment: You can use the [Xamarin Community Toolkit Camera View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/cameraview) and embed the camera inside any view and there decide to use only the front camera.